# Wiring a 2-pin K1 to a 3.5 mm jack with a mic and PTT?

Tags: switches, audio, wiring, microphone, plug

Is there a possibility to wire a 2-pin K1 headset connector to a 3.5 mm jack with a mic and using an external button for PTT in order to close the PTT circuit? If so, please help me, I have been thinking about this for a while now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want to use a radio with standard phone headset? Or you want to use the radio headset with a standard phone?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what the device that the upper thing gets plugged in expects (how should we? this is just a very strange, seemingly very proprietary connector!), but it seems that, no.

The upper diagram suggest that PTT on one side shares a pin with MIC-, and on the other side with SPK-, so doing *something* (we don't know – maybe shorting them? Maybe inserting a defined resistor between them? Maybe putting a small capacitor between them?) when the PTT is pressed.

For that to work, you cannot connect MIC- and SPK- from the start.

But your TRRS connector has only one negative side for both speakers and microphone, so they're inherently connected.

Comment: It is a connector for a radio, shorting both PTT pins activates them

Comment: yeah, so then my answer is 100% on point: since the TRRS connector inherently shorts microphone- and speaker-, you can't build this as an adapter cable.